# Jquery: Call a change function on document load

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using jquery in ASP.NET MVC 4. I have a textbox with id='ContactID' that has a change event. When 'ContactID' changes, the value in the textbox is used in an ajax call that talks to a database and returns a JSON result, which I then use to populate other textboxes on the page. From that point, there are certain fields that I require to be either readonly or not depending if the JsonResult populated the text box; this is so the user can input values into these textboxes if they are blank. If a textbox was populated, make the text box readonly, else make the textbox not readonly. This works great, but when the user submits the form, all values on the page become editable again. This is behavior that I do not want.

My question is: Is there a way to call my ContactID.change function when the page loads, but only when ContactID is not blank?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form :input:enabled:visible:first").focus();
    $("form :input:enabled:visible:first").select();
    $(".input-validation-error").first().focus();
    $(".input-validation-error").first().select();

    //I want to check to see if the ContactID textbox is populated when the document is ready
      //If ContactID is populated, I want the ContactID.change function to run
});

$('#ContactID).change(function () {
    var contactIDValue = $('#ContactID).val();

    if (contactIDValue.length != 0) { 
        //ContactID is populated; attempt to get Contact information

        //these fields should never be modified if using a ContactID
        $('#ContactStreet2').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact2Name').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact1Phone').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact2Phone').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact1Fax').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact2Fax').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact1Email').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#Contact2Email').attr('readonly', true);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetContactInformationFromContactID", "RelevantController")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { ContactIDValue : contactIDValue },
            success: function (contact) {

                //set all text boxes to the contact's information
                $('#ContactStreet1').val(contact.STREET1);
                $('#ContactStreet2').val(contact.STREET2);
                $('#ContactCity').val(contact.CITY);
                $('#ContactState').val(contact.STATE);
                $('#ContactZip').val(contact.ZIP);
                $('#ContactCountry').val(contact.POINTID);
                $('#Contact1Name').val(contact.CONTACT1NAME);
                $('#Contact2Name').val(contact.CONTACT2NAME);
                $('#Contact1Phone').val(contact.CONTACT1PHONE);
                $('#Contact2Phone').val(contact.CONTACT2PHONE);
                $('#Contact1Fax').val(contact.CONTACT1FAX);
                $('#Contact2Fax').val(contact.CONTACT2FAX);
                $('#Contact1Email').val(contact.CONTACT1EMAIL);
                $('#Contact2Email').val(contact.CONTACT2EMAIL);

                //disable or enable based on whether the field is populated
                if (contact.STREET1 != null && contact.STREET1.length > 0) {
                    $('#ContactStreet1').attr('readonly', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ContactStreet1').attr('readonly', false);
                }

                if (contact.CITY != null && contact.CITY.length > 0) {
                    $('#ContactCity').attr('readonly', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ContactCity').attr('readonly', false);
                }

                if (contact.STATE != null && contact.STATE.length > 0) {
                    $('#ContactState').attr('readonly', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ContactState').attr('readonly', false);
                }

                if (contact.ZIP != null && contact.ZIP.length > 0) {
                    $('#ContactZip').attr('readonly', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ContactZip').attr('readonly', false);
                }

                if (contact.POINTID != null && contact.POINTID.length > 0) {
                    $('#ContactCountry').attr('readonly', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ContactCountry').attr('readonly', false);
                }

                if (contact.CONTACT1NAME != null && contact.CONTACT1NAME.length > 0) {
                    $('#Contact1Name').attr('readonly', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#Contact1Name').attr('readonly', false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        //ContactID is not populated; enable all Text boxes
        $('#ContactStreet1').val(''); $('#ContactStreet1').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#ContactStreet2').val(''); $('#ContactStreet2').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#ContactCity').val(''); $('#ContactCity').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#ContactState').val(''); $('#ContactState').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#ContactZip').val(''); $('#ContactZip').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#ContactCountry').val(''); $('#ContactCountry').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact1Name').val(''); $('#Contact1Name').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact2Name').val(''); $('#Contact2Name').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact1Phone').val(''); $('#Contact1Phone').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact2Phone').val(''); $('#Contact2Phone').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact1Fax').val(''); $('#Contact1Fax').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact2Fax').val(''); $('#Contact2Fax').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact1Email').val(''); $('#Contact1Email').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#Contact2Email').val(''); $('#Contact2Email').attr('readonly', false);
    }
});
```

One way I thought I could accomplish this was doing something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form :input:enabled:visible:first").focus();
        $("form :input:enabled:visible:first").select();
        $(".input-validation-error").first().focus();
        $(".input-validation-error").first().select();

        var contactIDValue = $('#ContactID).val();

        if (contactIDValue.length != 0) {
             //a lot of failure on my part going on here -_-
        }
    });
```

But I can't find anywhere that states how to call a change function like I am wanting. Anyone know how I can do this? All help would be greatly appreciated, no matter how small!

Comment: There are syntax errors, code outside the DOM ready function that should probably be inside it, missing quotes etc. Fix the obvious first and you'll have a better change of getting it working, just open the console in your browser and you'll see all the errors.

Comment: I'm curious about opening the developer console in a browser. I've seen people using it, but I've never known how to open it myself. Do you know how I can go about doing this on IE10?

Comment: Sure, in IE10 you go to the Chrome download pages and download the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `.change()` which will trigger the registered change event handlers. But make sure that the event is triggered after the desired handlers are registered

```
$('#ContactID').change()
```

Comment: That solved it. I'll mark it as an answer when the answer timer expires. Thanks a lot!